# Not a statetment (Compiler Error Java/Android)

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

I am trying to do a simple if Statement using the ? pattern. Resulting in an "Not a statement"- Error. Can someone please explain to me why this is not happening using a normal if statement?

Error:

```
cursor.isNull(0) ? insert_SQL_RSServer.bindNull(0) : insert_SQL_RSServer.bindLong(0, cursor.getLong(0)); // id
```

No Error:

```
if(cursor.isNull(0))
    insert_SQL_RSServer.bindNull(0);
else
    insert_SQL_RSServer.bindLong(0, cursor.getLong(0));
```

This is completely the same behavior ....

Comment: you need to assign the result to some variable.

Comment: `insert_SQL_RSServer.bindNull(0)` and `insert_SQL_RSServer.bindLong(0, cursor.getLong(0))` should have a return type.. In your case it must be void..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ternary conditional operator is an expression, and it must have a return type, which is determined by the types of the 2nd and 3rd operands.

Therefore, if your `bindNull()` and `bindLong()` methods have `void` return type, they can't be used in this operator.

Comment: @Eran - What you are saying is true, but it doesn't actually explain the error message.  The `insert_...` calls >>are<< statements.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, an expression is not a statement except in the case of the following:

```
StatementExpression:
    Assignment
    PreIncrementExpression
    PreDecrementExpression
    PostIncrementExpression
    PostDecrementExpression
    MethodInvocation
    ClassInstanceCreationExpression
```

Reference: [JLS 14.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8).

A ternary expression is not one of the above.

> Thanks! But this is still bullshit... However..

It is the way that it is.  This is how Java is specified.

This could simply be a design choice that reflected the language designers' personal taste / views on simplicity. Alternatively, there could be a deeper reason or reasons for the choice; e.g. it might have solved some issue with ambiguous parses.